# CRM2011: Home page ribbon enable rule doesn't work properly

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

In my lead home page, there is a custom button. The enable rule for that button is:

```html
<EnableRule Id="enableruleid">
   <SelectionCountRule AppliesTo="SelectedEntity" Minimum="1" Maximum="1"></SelectionCountRule>
   <CustomRule FunctionName="functionname" Library="$Webresource:myjavascript.js">
           <CrmParameter Value="SelectedControlSelectedItemIds" />
    </CustomRule>
 </EnableRule>
```

The javascript working fine only for the first time select a record, when you select another record, the javascript doesn't called.

For example, I select record A, the button is enabled and it's fine; and then I select record B, the button should be disabled, but it's not, it still enabled.

But if I select record B first, the ribbon is disabled as I wish, and then I select record A, the button still disabled.

Anyone know why it like this?
Any suggestions?

**Update:** If I select multiple records, and then un-select most of them only left one, the enable rule works. Or I select one record --> un-select it --> select another record, it also works. The problem only occurs when I directly click on the "row" instead of the checkbox.

Comment: What is the JavaScript doing?

Comment: Hi @JamesWood, the javascript only do one thing, check the record's statecode and return true of false.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what the enable rule should do, e.g. what is the requirement?

Comment: Requirement is - if record's statecode is 0, enable the button; else disable the button.

Answer (score 2):

Well your rule states that a `minimum` of 1 record must be selected, so, selecting one record or more records would seem to qualify for leaving the button enabled.

Perhaps you should also include a `maximum`?

[SelectionCountRule (RibbonDiffXml)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309316.aspx)

Comment: Still doesn't work, I changed the enable rule in my question.